# Events with jQuery don't work when running `phonegap run android --device` command

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap

Hi I'm a begginer with phonegap framework,I have an issue when runing the command 'phonegap run android --device' the jquery events doesn't work, but if running 'phonegap serve' on my device with phonegap developer it works correctly.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you run serve command? Also, did you install PhoneGap and then immediately updated it?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, when I run the command 'phonegap run android --device' the events with jquery don't work, but if running 'phonegap serve' on my device with phonegap developer it works correctly.

Comment: Perfect, still, are you getting any errors? And please update your question to reflect the actual state of your question.